# Can't display tabulator widget in Pyscript

Tags: python, panel, tabulator, pyscript

There is a task to display Dataframe in browser using Pyscript. It uses Panel and Tabulator. the point is that Tabulator is not displayed. The code is attached. This code is not working

```
<html>

<head>
 
    
</head>

<body>
<div id="simple_app"></div>
    <py-script>

import panel as pn

    // Создаем DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({
      'int': [1, 2, 3],
      'float': [3.14, 6.28, 9.42],
      'str': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
      'bool': [True, False, True]
    })

    table = pn.widgets.Tabulator(df)   
    pn.Row(table).servable(target='simple_app')

    </py-script>
</body>

</html>
```

The ideal solution is to add some fileinput fields (which are responsible for loading csv) and a button after clicking which the loaded csv will be displayed using Tabulator widget

Comment: All imports are done 
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-3.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@holoviz/panel@1.3.0/dist/panel.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2022.12.1/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2022.12.1/pyscript.js"></script>